# Amazon MWS API returning InvalidParameterValue on GetMyFeesEstimate request

Tags: php, api, client, amazon-mws

I have a script that sends some ASINs to Amazon in order to retrieve their FeeEstimates, i'm using a php client for the api.

Here is the main part of my code:

```
       $n = count($products);
       $amazonFeesAux['MarketplaceId'] = 'my-market-place-id';
       $amazonFeesAux['IdType'] = 'ASIN';
       $amazonFeesAux['ListingPrice']['CurrencyCode'] = 'EUR';  
       $amazonFeesAux['IsAmazonFulfilled'] = true;

       echo 'Total number of unique ASINs: ' . $n;

       for($i = 1; $i <= $n; ++$i)
       {
            $amazonFeesAux['IdValue'] = $products[$i - 1]['ASIN'];
            $amazonFeesAux['ListingPrice']['Value'] = $products[$i - 1]['price'];
            $amazonFeesAux['Identifier'] = $i;   
            array_push($amazonFees, $amazonFeesAux);

            if($i % $this->requestQuota == 0)
            {
                if (++$batchN > $this->requestQuota) sleep(2);    //  wait 2 seconds to restore 20 items before next request

                echo "\n========================================= Batch number: " . $batchN . " =============================================== \n";

                $newAmazonProductRanks = $this->getAmazonProductFeesData($amazonFees);
                $amazonFees = [];       // reset array as to re-populate with next batch
                $this->updateProductFees($newAmazonProductRanks); <-- do something with the fees
            }
       }
```

Here, my `$products` is just my array of ASINs, and `$this->getAmazonProductFeesData` is just my function which sends the request to amazon. Everything works fine but for some ASINs I get back a vague `Client Side Error` which looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what am I doing wrong or missing here?

PS: This code uses `GetMyFeesEstimate` original MWS api request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue too, with a particular ASIN. I was able to verify this using the MWS Scratchpad. Other ASINs using the Scratchpad works find though.

Comment: try to put IsAmazonFulfilled="false"

Comment: @ÁronPopAdorján That does work for the ASIN (B095R3Z18D) I was having issue with. However, I need to get the FBA fee so setting isAmazonFulfilled to false is not an option for me. Thanks.